# Kibana doesn't show the user, and doesn't allow to manage users / roles

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, kibana

Scenario:

- Elasticsearch 7.2 (basic license) and Kibana 7.2
- xpack.security.enabled: true
- I used elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive to assign passwords to built-in users

I try to access Kibana, and it challenges me for user credentials, as expected.
I log in with the user "elastic" (which should be the super-user, right?), and enter. But:
I cannot see any user icon on top-right 
I cannot see the user / role management features

Can you help to understand where I'm wrong, please?

Comment: I guess you get prompted with your browser's basic authentication form instead of the kibana forms login, don't you?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill Huh... yeah, indeed, you're right. So...?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue a little while ago. If you get prompted by your browser for basic authorization instead of the kibana login form, it means that you have secured the elasticsearch cluster **but you have not enabled security in kibana itself**.

This basic auth login prompt you see is actually from Elasticsearch not Kibana (while Kibana makes requests on your behalf to Elasticsearch). Kibana is setup for anonymous access (security implicitly is disabled) and this is why you don't see an icon with your user on the far right as you would expect.

You need to set

`xpack.security.enabled: true`

in your Kibana environment as well.

Furthermore you have to provide the password for the built-in kibana user in the configuration via the settings:

```
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "kibanapassword"
```

See this guide (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.2/using-kibana-with-security.html) on how to configure security in kibana.

Comment: Interesting. However here:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.2/security-settings-kb.html it is written: "xpack.security.enabled: By default, Kibana automatically detects whether to enable the security features based on the license and whether Elasticsearch security features are enabled.  ". Then Kibana is supposed to know implicitly that the security feature is ON. It looks like it's not always like that. Thank you so much

Comment: @Flatline1963 Did it solve the issue? If yes, I would really appreciate if you would upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: well, as a matter of facts I had to reinstall both ES and Kibana, as it was clearly something wrong in my installation, as things were not working as documented. However you were right and pointed me to the right direction (Kibana security and ES security are two different animals), so I'm gratefully upvoting your answer.